# How can I check if my line matches the NFA?

Tags: python, algorithm, nfa, automaton

I made NFA that makes from regular expressions 3d array, for example (01*) expression. I get it:

```
[[FROM,TO,TRANSITION]]

    [['q0', 'q1', '0'], ['q1', 'q2', ':e:'] ,['q1', 'q4', ':e:'] ,
    ['q2', 'q3', '1'], ['q3', 'q2', ':e:'], ['q3', 'q4', ':e:']
```

How do I write a method that can test a string that satisfies this automaton? For example `"011111"` will return `q0 q1 q2 q3 q2 q3 q2 q3 q2 q3 q2 q3 q4`

Comment: Well, would you know how to do it if the automaton was deterministic?

Comment: (if yes, apply search-engine foo for the algorithm to construct the DFA)

Comment: There are plenty of existing libraries that you could use, so you do not have to re-invent the weel. I would suggest http://www.brics.dk/automaton/, an industrial-strength, easy-to-use automaton package for Java. It does exactly what you want. It is also pretty easy to extend the Automaton class if you need more information about which particular transitions have been taken in order to match a given string.

Comment: Are ":e:" epsilon transitions? It seems like "q4" is the accepting state -- but where is that expressed?

Comment: Paul Hankin, I'm sorry I forgot about it. You wrote correctly

Answer (score 1):

1. You can convert the automaton to DFA (after that checking becomes trivial). This approach is useful is the NFA is small but the number of strings you're going to test is pretty big.
2. You can also build a new graph where each vertex is pair (state of the NFA, position in the string). There's an edge between a state and another state for each position if it's an epsilon transition. There's also an edge `(s, pos) -> (s', pos + 1)` if the character for the `s->s'` transition in the automaton matches the character at position `pos` in the string. 
   After building the graph, you just need to check that a pair `(t, string.length())` is reachable for at least one terminal state `t` (you can use any graph traversal algorithm to check it, for instance a depth-first search).